Optimal Methods for Reducing Nitrogen Concentration from 16 mg/L to 9 mg/L in Treated Wastewater prior to entering an RO membrane
I am currently working on a project that involves reducing nitrogen concentration in water from 16 mg/L to 9 mg/L. I am looking for the most effective and efficient methods for nitrogen removal, particularly in terms of practicality and cost-effectiveness(except the activated sludge method).
Nitrogen is primarily in the form of [Ammonium=2 ppm, nitride=3 ppm, and nitrate=11 ppm]. which mean in total TN=16 ppm
I am dealing with [treated wastewater].
The volume of water that needs treatment is [8500 m3/d].
I need to propose a method to reduce the total nitrogen to 9 ppm. Even though there are COD and BOD levels in the water of 60 and 30 ppm respectively, I have decided to remove them using Ozonation and aeration. However, I am unsure how to reduce the total nitrogen.
Questions:
What methods are most effective for reducing nitrogen concentrations in this range?
Are there any specific technologies or treatment systems you would recommend?
What are the expected costs and maintenance requirements associated with these methods?
Are there any case studies or empirical data that demonstrate the effectiveness of these methods?

What about dilution?

@SolarMike he's wanting to feed an RO system, so wrong direction.

There are some good books about water treatment methods - what have you already considered except activated sludge of course?

OP, please show the plant layout, siting of the treatment facility, and siting of the RO plant. If you have the land, a denitrifying swamp is a good option if you can create a favorable environment for heterotrophs. What is the end use of the RO system, and what are the specs of the product? Is the RO output about 100 l /min, or is that flow the feed? What is the reject rate of your RO system?

@PhilSweet The Op states 8500m3/day - does that come out to 100L/min?

@SolarMike no, it doesn't. I computed it as a per second flow - it's 100 l/sec. thanks.

@PhilSweet 8500 m3/d > 8500000 l/d > 8500000 / 24 = 354166 l/hr > 354166 / 60  = 5903 l/min at least that's what I get.

@SolarMike fixed above - now I'm going to drink my coffee and wake up.

@PhilSweet enjoy the coffee and what remains of your weekend! Sorry didn't see your correction until the server updated after I posted...

@PhilSweet Thanks for the answer please tell me why the direction is wrong ?  please note that the RO system is the client's scope of work and what I will do in this project is to purify water before entering RO with the following quality : ( BOD=30 ppm, COD 60 ppm, TSS 40 pm, NH4-N=2 ppm, NO2-N=3 ppm, NO3-N= 11 ppm, TN= 16 ppm, TP= 6 ppm, pH=8.5 to 6.5 ) to target quality ( BOD=5 ppm, COD=10 ppm, TSS=5 ppm, NO3=8.8 ppm, NO2= 0.03, PO4=0.37 ppm).

@SolarMike The references that I considered are just Metcalf and Qasim which offer methods like activated sludge, MBR, EBPR, and the methods where the required nitrogen needs to be more than 100 ppm.

@PhilSweet  Are there any coagulants that can remove nitrogen from the treated wastewater?
